# Как можно решить это задание?

Tags: python, html, веб-программирование, postgresql, flask

[image]

Само задание: Реализуйте веб приложение для отслеживания клиентов и сотрудников по помещениям больницы. Эта система позволяет отслеживать перемещение людей по зонам доступа в больнице, контролировать доступ к определенным помещениям и управлять доступом сотрудников и посетителей. В ресурсах представлена карта отделения с расположением помещений и пропускных пунктов. Необходимо сделать отображение заполненности помещений, получая данные о перемещениях клиентов и персонала каждые 3 секунды посредством API согласно предоставленной документации(api уже есть). Персонал на карте необходимо выделить синими кружочками, а клиентов - зелеными. Расположение людей на карте внутри помещения (после зафиксированного входа или выхода) должно быть случайным образом (без наложения кружочков друг на друга). Как это можно реализовать на python? Нужны просто идеи посредством чего это можно выводить в веб

Comment: А что, интересная задача, и человек не просит её прямо за него решить, не понимаю, почему минусуют. Хотя на `Python` тут разве что бэк сделать, а вот как лучше это отрисовать всё на фронте - я лично как бэкэндщик не представляю.

Comment: вот и я не представляю, если честно, было бы хорошо, если бы кто - то смог подсказать хотя бы минимально как такое сделать можно, потому что в сети я такого не нахожу

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, фронт нужно будет на JS писать, используя что-то такое например https://two.js.org/

Comment: Непонятно, какого рода проблемы возникли у автора вопроса. (И какие именно идеи нужны.) Как перевести  данные о перемещениях в данные о присутствии в помещениях? Как отобразить данные в веб?  Как распознавать картинку со схемой датчиков (чтобы распознать связность помещений)?  Если отвечать на все вопросы -  фактически сделать задание за автора.

Comment: @CrazyElf необязательно. Можно картинку генерировать (svg).

Comment: @Chorkov скорее как все это отрисовать в вебе

Comment: @Chorkov Ну, можно просто обрисовать общую схему, что автор и просит. Где что можно использовать и т.п.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этапы работы / блоки которые можно отлаживать отдельно:

1. Разобрать схему на граф связей: составить список зон; соответствие номеров датчиков и связанных этой дверью помещений.
2. Написать процедуру которая будет преобразовывать данные о перемещении в данные о присутствии сотрудников в каждом помещении. Возможно, потребуется хранить какие-то данные потребуется хранить персистентно (например в базе данных, но можно и просто в текстовом файле). Можно (необязательно) оформить в виде отдельного микросервиса.
3. Нарисовать картинку со схемой помещения в svg-редакторе. Разместить на ней области, в которых будут рисоваться кружки (чтобы не закрывать названия помещений). Тут много вариантов: можно Jinga2, если понимаете как устроен svg изнутри; можно сипользовать библиотеки типа svgwrite / drawsvg. SVG лучше чем PNG, тем что можно делать всплывающие подсказки на элементах картинки и гиперссылки.
4. Написать функцию (или отдельную программу), которая вставляет кружочки на картинку. Т.е. рисует требуемую по ТЗ схему при каждом вызове.
5. Интеграция с веб сервером. Тут надо надо смотреть какой сервер у заказчика. Как правило, в файле настройки сервера, нужно прописать что при запросе заданного URL, запустить ваш файл, и вернуть его выдачу в качестве ответа клиенту.
6. Автоматическое обновление картинки (повторный запрос) решать на стороне клиента, средствами JavaScript.